# Wrong properties DB for copied model

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

I am using linked model with 2 buildings(building A and building B).
I have 1 central file that linked to those rvt files.
I uploaded the model with Forge-API and open it with the viewer.
It looks like that the properties in the building B are taken from A for those elements that exist in both models.
For example: In the attached picture there is 2 walls that has exactly the same properties but clearly they are different.
Note that building B RVT file was copied from building A RVT and changed as needed.
This is why the element externalId is the same for both of the walls after the "/".
But before the "/" it is different.
How can this be solved ?

1. Any way to change externalId in Revit after the copy?
2. Something in the translation process to SVG2?

By the way, the same happened in the free Autodesk viewer.

Thank you !

[2 walls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpkjB.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly is the issue here? The wall you modified in building B still has the same type so I would expect it to have the same number of properties, with most of them having the same values (except for properties like area or volume). And since building B is just a copy of building A, I would also expect the external IDs to look like this, with the part before `/` representing the specific Revit model, and the part after `/` representing the GUID of the specific wall instance.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
The problem is that all the properties are the same, even the volume area and etc.
You can create model with one wall in it.
Copy the model, edit the wall size.
Connect both model with links and upload it.
Both walls will have the same measurements

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Would you mind sharing the dataset with us (confidentially; we wouldn't share it with anyone outside of Autodesk) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`? We'd be happy to pass it on to the engineering team for further investigation.